# Swift. Load collectionView by n elements

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm very new to iOS development and Swift.
I have a UICollectionView that populates images from the array. My idea is to load initially 10 images and let user scroll to the bottom of the collectionView and then load next 10 images from the array by pressing button 'more' or just automatically.
Can you suggest the best way to do it?
My code is:

```
self.searches.insert(results, at: 0)
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                                 cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        //1
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier,
                                                      for: indexPath) as! CatPhotoCell
        // this methods takes one photo from searches array
        let flickrPhoto = photoForIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath)

        cell.imageView.image = flickrPhoto.thumbnail
        cell.cat_name.text = flickrPhoto.title

        return cell
    } 

private extension CatsPhotosCollectionViewController {
    func photoForIndexPath(indexPath: IndexPath) -> FlickrPhoto {
        return searches[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section].searchResults[(indexPath as IndexPath).row]
    }
}
```

Comment: Pagination is the word you're looking for.. `willDisplayCellForItemAtIndexPath` if the last cell or 5th to last cell is displaying, load more.. so on and so forth..

Answer (score 1):

`func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView){
//step 2 here
}`

1.Intially set array count as 10.

2.Increase array count whatever you want inside the above function and reload collectionView.

Comment: Do you mean array that is a source for the collectionView?